# Countdown Timer for each new card in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, timer, countdowntimer, cardlayout

I am using CardLayout to display a series of questions. For each question, there is a timer displayed on a label.
I pass the questions and the time limit for each question from the main class.

```
//Reference - SynforgeTutorials
public class Quiz extends JFrame{
    JPanel p=new JPanel();
    CardLayout cards=new CardLayout();
    int numQs;


    int cardnumber;

    CL1 questions[];



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] messages = {"What is area of a circle?","When does spring start?","When is the next leap year?","How many days in a week?","What causes seasons?"};
        int[] mins = {1,2,0,1,1};
        int[] secs = {30,0,30,0,0};
        new Quiz(messages,mins,secs);
    } 

    public Quiz(String messages[],int mins[],int secs[]){


        questions = new CL1[messages.length];

        for(int i=0;i<questions.length;i++)
        {
        questions[i] = new CL1(messages[i],mins[i],secs[i],this);

        }

        p.setLayout(cards);

        numQs=questions.length;
        for(int i=0;i<numQs;i++){
            p.add(questions[i],"q"+i);
        }

        cardnumber = 0;

        cards.show(p,"q"+ cardnumber);


        add(p);
        setVisible(true);


    }

    public void OK(){
        if(cardnumber==(numQs-1)){

            this.dispose();

        }
        else{

            cardnumber = cardnumber + 1;
            cards.show(p,"q"+ cardnumber);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the class that constructs the cards. It has 3 panels - the top panel where the question is displayed, the center panel where the Minutes and Seconds are displayed on a label along with a Pause and Resume button, and the bottom panel where the OK button is present. On clicking the 'OK' button, the next card is displayed.

```
public class CL1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    int correctAns;

    Quiz quiz;
    int selected;
    boolean used;

    private Timer myTimer1;
    public long initialTimeInSecs;
    public long elapsedTime;
    public long convertToSecs;
    public String minutes;
    public String seconds;
    public String clockTimeString; 
    public static final int ONE_SEC = 1000;
    Font myClockFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);




    //Message
    JPanel qPanel=new JPanel();

    //Timer
    JPanel tPanel=new JPanel();
    JLabel timeLbl = new JLabel("New label");
    JButton btnPause=new JButton("Pause");
    JButton btnResume=new JButton("Resume");


    //bottom
    JPanel botPanel=new JPanel();
    JButton OK=new JButton("OK");



    public CL1(String q, int userMinutes, int userSeconds, Quiz quiz){

        this.quiz=quiz;

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        //Message
        qPanel.add(new JLabel(q));
        add(qPanel);


        //Timer
        convertToSecs = (userMinutes * 60) + userSeconds;

        initialTimeInSecs = convertToSecs;
        elapsedTime = initialTimeInSecs;

        seconds = Integer.toString((int)(elapsedTime % 60));
        minutes = Integer.toString((int)((elapsedTime % 3600) / 60));
        if (seconds.length() < 2)
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        if (minutes.length() < 2)
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        clockTimeString = (minutes+":"+seconds).toString();

        timeLbl.setText(clockTimeString);
        timeLbl.setFont(myClockFont);
        timeLbl.setBorder(raisedbevel);

        myTimer1 = new Timer(ONE_SEC,new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                initialTimeInSecs = initialTimeInSecs - 1;

                elapsedTime = initialTimeInSecs;

                String seconds = Integer.toString((int)(elapsedTime % 60));
                String minutes = Integer.toString((int)((elapsedTime % 3600) / 60));


                if (seconds.length() < 2)
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;

                if (minutes.length() < 2)
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;

                clockTimeString = (minutes+":"+seconds).toString();

                timeLbl.setText(clockTimeString);

                if(clockTimeString.equals("00:00"))
                {
                    myTimer1.stop();

                }
                } 

          });

        myTimer1.start(); 



        btnPause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {   
                PauseBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });



        btnResume.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {   
                ResumeBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tPanel.add(timeLbl);
        tPanel.add(btnPause);
        tPanel.add(btnResume);

        add(tPanel);


        //bottom

        OK.addActionListener(this);

        botPanel.add(OK);

        add(botPanel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object src=e.getSource();
        //OK button
        if(src.equals(OK)){

            quiz.OK();}

    }

    public void PauseBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        myTimer1.stop();
    }

    public void ResumeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        myTimer1.start();
    }
}
```

The timer doesn't seem to refresh with every new label. It starts ticking from the start of the first label. However, for every other label, it subtracts the time elapsed from the start and not for that particular question from the current card's time limit and displays that.

For eg, For question 1 , time limit is 1.30
        For question 2 , time limit is 2.00 
        For question 3 , time limit is 3.00

The dialog box first shows the first label and starts ticking down from 1.30. Say I stayed on this label for 10 secs before pressing 'OK'.

Then the second label is displayed and the timer starts ticking down from 1.50 ( 2.00-0.10, instead of 2.00 ). 
Say I stay on this question for 25 secs before pressing 'OK'.

Then the third label is displayed and the timer starts ticking down from 2.25 ( 3.00-(0.10+0.25), instead of 3.00 ).

Even when I press the pause button, the timer doesn't seem to stop calculating. When I press the resume button, the timer takes into account the time elapsed while pausing and displays the time.

Any ideas on what is going wrong with this timer ?

Comment: In the code above pause and resume buttons work just fine for me.

Comment: Yes, the pause and resume buttons work fine. But the timer is not calculating properly. When i press pause, the time displayed on the label pauses and then resumes correctly. But when I go the next card, the time elapsed in the pause is also subtracted. So it ends up ticking down from the wrong time limit.

Comment: Each of the cards has it's own timer, and you start it in the `CL1` constructor. You should instead start the timer when you show the card (and do any modifications you want to the available time before that).

Comment: How can I start the timer when I show the card ? I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: You can add an accessor to `CL1` for the timer. Then, when you show the card, also call `cl1.getTimer().start()`, where `cl1` is the shown `CL1`, and `getTimer()` is the accessor for the timer. (Basically `public Timer getTimer() { return myTimer1; }` in `CL1`).